# Is there a way to add metadata to links in TFS or Visual Studio Online?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I want to express dependencies with links.  A is dependent on B.  I would like to be able to express that A needs B by some Date.  Is there a way to annotate the link with a date?

Comment: The work item tracking capabilities are aimed at Agile teams. The only dates that matter in that context are sprint start and sprint end. It sounds like you're closer to Waterfall, in which case you should look at Microsoft Project for managing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is valuable to understand your dependencies, especially if you have more than 2 teams working together on the same product you can't add dates to the link.

You can however add the rate to the feature or epic that are related. At this time there is no delivery date or required by date in VSO Associated with a PBI or a bug. Customisation of work items is due in the near future on VSO so that you can add that field.